# Neither onKeyListener nor TextWatcher able to receive soft keyboard inputs

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have looked at many posts and similiar questions have been asked. But none of the solution is working. First of all I've tried using `onKeyListener`, but in many posts, it is stated that it does not work for soft keyboard. So I tried to use `TextWatcher` instead, but it still does not printout anything.

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private MainThread thread;
private EditText editText;
private Bitmap textBitmap;

public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);

    //Add callback to the surfaceview to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //Make GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,int width, int height){}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

    editText = new EditText(getContext());
    editText.setSingleLine(true);
    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    editText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    editText.layout(0, 0, WIDTH - 200, 100);
    editText.buildDrawingCache();

    textBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(editText.getDrawingCache());

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    //Start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

    /*editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ABCD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });*/

    /*editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
        }
    });*/
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    System.out.println("ABC");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editText.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                //imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(textBitmap,50,50,null);
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
        }
    }
```

Does drawing EditText with canvas.drawBitmap have anything to do with those solutions not working? Or is there any mistakes on implementing them?

Any solutions are welcomed, need explanations if possible. Thanks!

EDIT : tried to use onEditorActionListener

Answer (score 0):

First of all check
**Did you include this line in your xml inside the EditText**

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

if not, please add it first.
Next for e.g i wanna use `Done` button inside my soft keyboard, than here is what you can do.

```
<EditText 
    android:id="edName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:singleLine="true"    //this line to take input in single line (if you don't include this line, Done button will not take any actions)
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>   //this line to provide done button
```

Now to take the input from keyboard for done button, add this code after `findViewById` in your `onCreate`

```
//TODO softKey "Done" listener for keyboard
edName.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //Do what you want here
                return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I do not use xml at all to program the edittext. I make edittext as bitmap and draw it on canvas

Comment: Okay than whatever is your edittext name, set this property progamatically `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` and try putting `setOnEditorActionListener` as i suggested.

Comment: I've edited my code in SurfaceCreated block as seen on the post. but 'done' button does not appear on soft keyboard. Any idea?

Comment: is it showing some other button instead of that...?

Comment: Yeah press that "Enter" button in the bottom right corner

Comment: I already edited my code using your suggestion as edited on my post now and pressed that 'Enter' button, but still, nothing was printed.

Comment: Use `Log.e("result", "ABC");` instead of `System.out.println("ABC");` and please add this too `editText.setSingleLine(true);`